# Update syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax

Is it possible to insert a from field in a update query?
i need it because before update something,i need to do some controls.
p.s i know that i have to use prepared statement but i want to know this error,i suppose it is a missing quote,that i can't see.
the error: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from warehouse,product where warehouse.idProduct=shop.idProduct and warehouse.id' at line 1`

```
int rs = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE shop SET quantity='"
                        + Quantity
                        + "' from warehouse,product where  
                         warehouse.idProduct=shop.idProduct and 
                         warehouse.idProduct=product.id and product.brand='"
                        + Brand + "' and product.productType='" + Product
                        + "'");
```

Comment: If you know you ought to use a prepared statement, why don't you do so? In the prepared statement, you won't have all those quotes anyway so the problem may just go away. Mind you, the code you've given us isn't valid Java...

Comment: I thought I could put in a update from a query, I was wrong, anyway I realized that prepared statements are easier to write and more protected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an update with a join:

```
UPDATE shop s join
       warehouse w
       on w.idProduct = s.idProduct join
       product p
       on w.idProduct = p.id and
          p.productType = '"+Product+"' and
          p.brand = '" + Brand + "'
    SET s.quantity = "+ Quantity
```

As a note.  I'm guess that `Quantity` is numeric.  If so, you don't need quotes around the value.

Answer (score 1):

That just isn't valid SQL. `UPDATE` statements cannot have a `FROM` clause.

```
Single-table syntax:

UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]

Multiple-table syntax:

UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

Comment: if i want to check something before update,how can i do?

Comment: Do a separate `SELECT` statement and then do your `UPDATE` based on the results.